# Pipe command output to Yad and also log the output to a logfile

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, io-redirection

Need to have the process of command typically an update to be shown using [yad](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yad-dialog/) and at the same time log all the output to a given log file set up.
This is what  I have

```
apt-get update | yad --width=400 --height=300 \
--title="Updating debian package list ..." --progress \
--pulsate --text="Updating debian package list ..." \
--auto-kill --auto-close \
--percentage=10
```

The above command creates a pulsating indicator for the process and closes on finish but I need to have it log all the output it gives I have tried

```
apt-get update >>${logfile} 2>&1 | yad --width=400 --height=300 \
--title="Updating debian package list ..." --progress \
--pulsate --text="Updating debian package list ..." \
--auto-kill --auto-close \
--percentage=10
```

but that gives me an error and hangs from there on no dialog and no logging just freezing. Here is the error

```
 GLib-CRITICAL **: g_source_remove: assertion `tag > 0' failed
```

Help appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because you are redirecting all output to `$logfile` so there is no output for `yad` to process. The tool you're looking for is `tee`:

```
NAME
       tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

SYNOPSIS
       tee [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.
```

So, you could do:

```
apt-get update 2>&1 | tee -a ${logfile} |
  yad --width=400 --height=300 \
    --title="Updating debian package list ..." --progress \
    --pulsate --text="Updating debian package list ..." \
    --auto-kill --auto-close \
    --percentage=10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to direct the output of `apt-get` into the logfile, run this process in the background, and "siphon" the increases to that logfile into a `yad` window with progress bar using `tail -f`:

```
apt-get update > "$logfile" & tail -f "$logfile" | yad --width=400 --height=300 \
--title="Updating debian package list ..." --progress \
--pulsate --text="Updating debian package list ..." \
--auto-kill --auto-close \
--percentage=10
```